# Not able to print char element of a strucure variable

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b1, b2, b3;
    char ch;
    printf("\nEnter the info of the books:\n");

    while ((ch = getchar()) == '\n' && ch != EOF) { }

    scanf_s("%c", &b1.name, sizeof(char));
    scanf_s("%f", &b1.price, sizeof(float));
    scanf_s("%d", &b1.pages, sizeof(int));

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {}

    scanf_s("%c", &b2.name, 1);
    scanf_s("%f", &b2.price, sizeof(float));
    scanf_s("%d", &b2.pages, sizeof(int));

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {}

    scanf_s("%c", &b3.name, 1);
    scanf_s("%f", &b3.price, sizeof(float));
    scanf_s("%d", &b3.pages, sizeof(int));

    printf("\n%c %f %d", b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages);
    printf("\n%c %f %d", b2.name, b2.price, b2.pages);
    printf("\n%c %f %d", b3.name, b3.price, b3.pages);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I'm not able to print name of b1 in the following program, I'm new in C, any help is appreciated.

Result

Enter the info of the books:

```
A 2454.45 344 
B 56566.55 355 
C 5676.66 566
```

The output is:

```
2454.45 344 
B 56566.55 355 
C 5676.66 566`
```

Comment: Your code block for b1 differs from the others. You use the literal 1 for b2 & b3 but `sizeof(char)` for b1. Use the literal for b1 too and it should work.

Comment: `char ch;` should be `int ch;`, because that is what `getchar()` returns.

Comment: The `%c` format in `scanf_s()` does require the size as an extra argument — as shown.  However, neither `%f` nor `%d` requires an extra size argument — that's true in both the standard C11 version of [`scanf_s()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4) and in the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l) version.

Comment: It seems that you need to study how strings work in C, simple as that.

Comment: @cramopy What should be gained with that change? `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
struct book b1, b2, b3;
char ch;
printf("\nEnter the info of the books:\n");

while ((ch = getchar()) == '\n' && ch != EOF) { }

scanf_s("%c", &b1.name, sizeof(char));
scanf_s("%f", &b1.price, sizeof(float));
scanf_s("%d", &b1.pages, sizeof(int));
```

The while statement is entirely unnecessary there. stdin is empty after the printf() call, it doesn't affect that, and the while loop eats up the first character of your input. Get rid of it and the code works as expected.

It's also maybe worth noting that you might want to stick to more standard functions when you're just learning. scanf_s is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: Technically, there is a version of `scanf_s()` specified in the C11 standard in optional [Annex K §3.5.3.4 The `scanf_s` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4).  However, apart from Microsoft, I think it is fair to say that no other system has implemented it, and there is a move afoot to remove the Annex K code from the next C standard, or at least to mark it as deprecated (for removal in a subsequent standard).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also I don't think the MS versions are compatible with C11. Best to stay away from the Visual Studio language entirely and write standard C instead.

Comment: Thanks @Roflcopter4 & everyone else, I've stopped using MS extensions by using #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS